# Nodejs - How to apply a function to each line combo of two streams?

Tags: node.js

I am streaming two large files that cannot fit in memory and I need to compare the two files line by line and apply a comparison function that needs to accumulate some information.

Assume I have two streams: `const stream1, stream2`. And some result I need to accumulate. For the sake of example, let's say it is a count of the number of lines that are the same at the same position in the two files: `let count`.

Here was the method I tried:

```
const stream1 = getLineByLineReadable1Somehow(), stream2 = getLineByLineReadable2Somehow();

let count = 0;

stream1.on('readable', () => {
    stream2.on('readble', () => {
        let line1, line2;
        while (line1 = stream1.read()) {
            line2 = stream2.read();
            if (line1 !== line2) count++;
        }
    });
});

console.log(count);
```

This works fine as long as the two files are small, but completely falls apart when the files get big. The count provided at the end is incorrect. Not sure what is happening but I think it's related to the `readable` event of one of the two streams getting triggered many times. At some point one of the two streams just spits out a bunch `null` for a while.

Would appreciate any help on this matter. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that on large files the event of the arrival of a new line can be extremely irregular. So it is necessary to have an intermediate buffer. It is a working snippet:

```
var readline = require('readline');
var fs = require('fs');

var rs1 = fs.createReadStream('1.log');
var r1 = readline.createInterface({
    input: rs1
});

var rs2 = fs.createReadStream('2.log');
var r2 = readline.createInterface({
    input: rs2
});

var stats = {
    count: [0, 0],
    common: 0,
    closed: 0,
    lines: [
        [],
        []
    ]
}

function compare(line, i) {
    stats.count[i]++;
    if (stats.closed === 0 || stats.lines[1 - i].length > 0) stats.lines[i].push(line);
    while (stats.lines[0].length > 0 && stats.lines[1].length > 0) {
        var L1 = stats.lines[0].shift();
        var L2 = stats.lines[1].shift();
        if (L1 === L2) stats.common++;
    }
}

function close() {
    if (++stats.closed === 2) console.log(stats.count, stats.common, stats.lines[0].length, stats.lines[1].length);
}

r1.on('line', (line) => compare(line, 0))
r2.on('line', (line) => compare(line, 1))

r1.on('close', close);
r2.on('close', close);
```